# For what values ​​of $m$ the function $y=x^m\sin(x)$ have horizontal asymptote

Tags: calculus, limits

I want to figure for what values ​​of $m$ the function have horizontal asymptote.$$y=x^m\sin(x)$$ 
so what I understand from that is this that the function dont have a vertical one, so I will find vertical asymptote and I will require that its equal to $0$: 
$$a=\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}$$
I need some advice how to continue from here.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{f(x)}x=x^{m-1}\sin x\xrightarrow[x\to\pm\infty]{}\begin{cases}0&,\,\,m-1<0\\{}\\\not\exists&,\;\;m-1\ge0\end{cases}$$